# Enabling Stack Smashing in Fedora 21

Tags: c, gcc, memory, stack

I am trying to write a C program to demonstrate writing to different areas of the stack to change the execution of a program during runtime.

I have this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* useless_function (int x) {
  int* somewhere_in_the_stack = &x;
  int* another_place = &x + 5;
  return (int*)((long int)(*another_place)) - 3;
}
int main () {
  int step = 3;
  int* q = useless_function(50);
  printf("%d %d\n",&step,q);
  //printf("%d %d\n",&step,*q);
}
```

that attempts to do just that. Basically useless_function returns the address of the local variable 'step' in the main function on the stack. When I compile and execute the program on my machine The printf prints out the same exact memory address for both 'step' and 'q', however in the commented out line when I try to deference 'q' I get a segmentation fault. I can however, to *(&step) without a segfault.

I tried to compile with the this option '-fno-stack-protector', but it did not work.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem more clearly.

Comment: You should look up the C ABI because x will be in a register, not on the stack!

Comment: My problem is that I cannot dereference the pointer q. At line 3 in function main &step is equal to q. I can dereference &step, but not q.

Comment: I already explained that the value returned pointer is truncated, i.e. NOT what was intended to be returned. So what's up with this?

Answer (score 0):

That's totally incorrect, but may have worked on a 32-bit platform.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* useless_function (int x) {
  int* somewhere_in_the_stack = &x;
  int* another_place = &x + 5;
```

A pointer to int.

```
  return (int*)((long int)(*another_place)) - 3;
```

Hence (*another_place) is an int. Then you cast it to long int. If the address did not fit in an int (and it typically does not), you *lose* a part of it. Then the result is sign-extended. Which you would have seen....

```
}
int main () {
  int step = 3;
  int* q = useless_function(50);
  printf("%d %d\n",&step,q);
```

You would have seen the truncation if you used the proper format specifier (%p). Interestingly enough gcc warns about the issue even without -Wall, so I'm additionally confused as to why you ask the question what's up prior to resolving reported issues.

Finally, a fun fact is that printf("%p\n", pointer); triggers undefined behavior unless the pointer is of type char * or void *.